# Image not stretching inside imageView android

Tags: android, imageview

I am having a layout in with root Relative layout and and ImageView inside it when i set it source the Image is not fitting inside into Image view leaving Top and and bottom padding which is in preview but not defined in xml. I want to know how to stretch image to fit completely in ImageView.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:background="#fff">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/place_demo_2"
        android:id="@+id/back_ground_place"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="400dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Manila Main"
        android:id="@+id/visit_place_title"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: set `android:scaleType="fitXY"` for the `ImageView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use android:scaleType in your XML file. There are several options you will probably want to play with until you get the exact product you are looking for but, if you don't care about aspect ratio, it sounds like you might want to use android:scaleType="fitXY".

You can find more information here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Below are the rest of the options:

> ImageView.ScaleType="CENTER"
>
> - Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling.
>
> ImageView.ScaleType="CENTER_CROP"
>
> - Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to
>     or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus
>     padding).
>
> ImageView.ScaleType="CENTER_INSIDE"
>
> - Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to
>     or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).
>
> ImageView.ScaleType="FIT_CENTER"
>
> - Scale the image using CENTER.
>
> ImageView.ScaleType="FIT_END"
>
> - Scale the image using END.
>
> ImageView.ScaleType="FIT_START"
>
> - Scale the image using START.
>
> ImageView.ScaleType="FIT_XY"
>
> - Scale the image using FILL.
>
> ImageView.ScaleType="MATRIX"
>
> - Scale using the image matrix when drawing.

Answer (score 3):

Using Code:

```
YourImageView.SetScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Using xml:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

See also below snapshots for other alternative options.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:scaleType` in your `ImageView`

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Check other available options for scaleType [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Answer (score 2):

either make width of Imageview to wrap_content
or 
you have to set android:scaleType of Imageview to fitXY

Answer (score 2):

Add to ImageView attr **`android:scaleType="fitXY"`**

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have aligned the ImageView to parent's bottom BUT there is a margin at the bottom of 400dp. 
Long story short,  remove
`android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 android:layout_marginBottom="400dp"`
Also set the `layout_height to match_parent` if you want the image to fill the whole screen. 
P. S.  Also `fill_parent` is deprecated, so use `match_parent` instead.

Comment: no i dont want to be it on whole screen but just attached top of the layout

Comment: Ok, no problem just remove `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_marginBottom="400dp"`

Comment: i did so and even tried <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/place_demo_2"
        android:id="@+id/back_ground_place"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       />

Comment: but still there is some padding inside ImageView

Comment: I believe that the margin is because of `android:layout_marginTop="68dp"` in your TextView. Use layout_paddingTop in your textview instead.